# Trouble with simple consequence of the polarization identity

Tags: linear-algebra

The polarization identity is
$[u,v] = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \|u + i^k v\|^2$,

where $[u,v]$ is any sesquilinear hermitian form. My instructor claims as a simple consequence that:

if $[v,v] = 0$ for all $v\in V$, then $[u,v] = 0$ for all $u,v\in V$.

I don't see where this is coming from and he just repeats that its a simple consequence. The only thing I can figure is that $[v,v] = 0$ for all $v$ implies that $\|v\|=0$ by equating real and imaginary parts from the polarization identity to zero. I'm not sure how this implies that $[u,v]=0$ for all $u,v\in V$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\| u\|^2$ indicates $[u,u]$, right?

Then $$[u,v] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3i^k [u + i^kv,u+i^kv] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3i^k[w_k,w_k] = 0$$

(writing out the last step isn't strictly necessary; it's just to help you see how this follows)

Comment: So are we essentially saying that if $[v,v]$ is always zero for every $v\in V$ that $V$ contains only the zero element? Because it wouldn't make sense to word our result this way if that was the case.

Comment: No, it means that $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the $0$-sesquilinear form. To be concrete, maybe we could write $[\cdot,\cdot]_A$ to indicate this form (reserving $[\cdot,\cdot]$ for the usual inner product), and write $\|v\|^2_A = [v,v]_A$ to indicate the induced norm (reserving $\|v\|^2 = [v,v]$ for the usual norm). I've chosen this notation because, as you might know, every sesquilinear form is given by $[u,v]_A = [u,Av]$ for some Hermitian $A$. In this case $[v,v]_A = 0$ for all $v \in V$ implies $A = 0$.

Comment: I guess I should mention that, unless $A$ is also positive definite, it is misleading to call $[v,v]_A$ a *norm* (one condition of a norm is that $\|v\|_A = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$, something that is obviously violated here, and I think is leading to your confusion).

Thus, it's probably most appropriate to write the polarization identity as $[u,v] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3i^k [u + i^kv,u+i^kv]$ instead of with $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: "as you might know, every sesquilinear form is given by $[u,v]_A=[u,Av]$ for some Hermitian A." We never mentioned this and are either skirting it completely or will come back to it later. We did however use the result in my question as a lemma in showing a result similar to the one involving the $A$ as you mention above, but our result for a linear operator $T$ and this was on the first component. We conclude that a $T$ such that $\langle Tu,v \rangle =0$ for all $u$ and $v$ must be the zero operator using the above lemma.

Comment: If polarization doesn't necessarily relate to norms then what is the polarization identity telling us? I don't get what information we're gleaning from polarization, it just seems to be a rewriting of what we already know.

Comment: 1) At this point, I didn't really *need* the fact that every sesq. form is related to a hermitian $A$, I just wanted *some* kind of notation to distinguish the $\|\cdot\|$ in your polar. ID from the usual vector space norm. 2) The difference between the first/second component (i.e. $[u,Av]$ vs. $\langle Tu,v\rangle$) is just a convention; don't worry about that.

Comment: 3) Suppose someone hands you a sesq. form, but only tells you how to compute $[w,w]$ for any $w$. You know it is *defined* for $[u,v]$, you just weren't told how to compute it. That is; you can compute the value if the *same* vector is in both places, but not for diff. vectors. The polarization identity allows you to get from one to the other: in order to compute $[u,v]$ you can do it in terms of $[u+v,u+v]$, $[u + iv,u+iv]$, $[u - v,u-v]$ and $[u-iv,u-iv]$ (all of those are of the form $[w,w]$ for some $w$)

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful.

Comment: I talked with my instructor and he said that we actually aren't assuming that the sesquilinear form is hermitian (unlike in my original question), is this standard? It doesn't seem to affect any of the proofs we've done, does it make a big difference anywhere else?

Comment: No, I don't think that has any consequences here - hermitian just means that $[v,u] = \overline{[u,v]}$. So there's kind of a hierarchy of forms - those which are just sesquilinear, then those which are sesq. and hermitian, and finally those that are sesq., herm. and positive definite. You need all three to define a inner-product/norm (if you have an inner-product (i.e. a sesq., herm., pos. def. form, you can define a norm from it: $\|u\|^2 = [u,u]$.), but you only need sesq. for the polarization ID to hold.

Comment: Ahh, and so I should revise one of my earlier statements. When I said "every sesq. form is given by $[u,v]_A = [u,Av]$ for some hermitian $A$" that wasn't accurate. It's just that (past the basic material you're covering now) one hardly ever considers sesq. forms that *aren't* Hermitian. Though I should have thought about that more carefully. I think the correct statement is $[u,v]_A = [u,Av]$ for some *linear* operator $A$ (and again, the difference between putting $A$ in the first or second argument is just convention).