# Consequence of the polarization identity?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Here is a proof which I do not fully understand.

> **Theorem :** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. A continuous linear map $T : H \rightarrow H$ is self-adjoint (hermitian) if and only if $$\big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle \in \mathbb{R},~~~~~(\forall x \in H)$$
>   **Proof :**
>   ($\Rightarrow$)
>   $$ \overline{\big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle} = \big\langle x, T(x)\big\rangle = \big\langle T^*(x),x \big\rangle = \big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle.$$
>   Therefore $$\big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle \in \mathbb{R}.$$
>   ($\Leftarrow$) Using the hypothesis we've got
>   $$ \Big\langle (T-T^*)(x), x\Big\rangle = \big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle  -  \big\langle x, T(x)\big\rangle = \big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle - \overline{\big\langle T(x), x\big\rangle} = 0$$
>   Therefore 
>   $$\Big\langle (T-T^*)(x), x\Big\rangle = 0,~~~~~(\forall x \in H).$$
>   By polarization identity
>   $$\Big\langle (T-T^*)(x), y\Big\rangle = 0,~~~~~(\forall x,y \in H).$$
>   Since $(T-T^*)(x)$ est orthogonal to every vecteur $y \in H$ we conclude that $(T-T^*) = 0$. Therefore $T = T^*$.

I don't get the "by the polarization identity" bit. How is it that the polarization identity allows us let the right term of the inner product range over $H$ independently from the left term ?!

**Edit :**
Seems related to [Trouble with simple consequence of the polarization identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572843/trouble-with-simple-consequence-of-the-polarization-identity)
in a way I'm currently trying to figure out.

Comment: Does auto adjoint mean self adjoint?

Comment: Yes it does. I edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that the polarization identity is true for **any** sesquilinear form on any complex vector space $V$. That is, if $g$ is any sesquilinear form on $V$ then we have

$$ g(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} \left( g(x + y, x + y) - g(x - y, x - y) + ig(x + iy, x + iy) -ig(x - iy, x - iy) \right) $$

for all $x, y \in V$. Note that this identity implies that if $g(z,z) = 0$ for all $z \in V$ then $g \equiv 0$.

Now, let $(V, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ be a complex inner product space and $S \colon V \rightarrow V$ be a complex linear map. If we define $g(x,y) := \left< Sx, y \right>$ then $g$ is a sesquilinear form on $V$ and if $g(z,z) = \left< Sz, z \right> = 0$ for all $z \in V$ then $g \equiv 0$ which implies in particular that $g(x, Sx) = ||Sx||^2 = 0$ for all $x \in V$ so $S = 0$.

Now apply this to $V = H$ and $S = T - T^{*}$.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the polarisation identity.

Suppose $\mathbb{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $\langle Ax,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$. Then $A=0$.

We have $\langle A(x+y),x+y\rangle = 0 = \langle Ax,y\rangle + \langle Ay,x\rangle = 0$.

Replacing $y$ by $iy$ we get $\langle A(x+iy),x+iy\rangle = 0 = i(\langle Ax,y\rangle - \langle Ay,x\rangle) = 0$ and combining with
the above we get $\langle Ax,y\rangle = 0$. Since this holds for all $x,y$ we see that $A=0$.

It is not true in a real Hilbert space, for example,
$A =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then
$\langle Ax,x\rangle = 0$ for all (real) $x$, but $A \neq 0$.

Comment: Isn't it $\langle Ax,y\rangle + \langle Ay,x\rangle$?

Comment: @HritRoy: Thank for catching that, I made a mistake. Will delete shortly.

Comment: @HritRoy: Actually, it had a simple fix, see above.

Comment: in $i(\langle Ax,y\rangle - \langle Ay,x\rangle) = 0$ , shouldn't we have a "+" instead?

Comment: @SamaelManasseh No, the inner product is linear in one variable but conjugate linear in the other.