# normal operator equation

Tags: linear-algebra

let $S: V \to V$ linear transformation in a inner product space of $\mathbb{C}$.

Prove that $S$ is normal iff $$\|S(x)\| = \|S^*(x)\|$$

That's what I have done so far:

if $S$ is normal than $$SS^* = S^*S \implies \|S(X)\|^2 = (S(x),S(x)) = (x, S^*S(x)) = (x,SS^*(x)) = (S^*(x), S^*(x)) = \|S^*(x)\|^2$$

Thats for the first part, how do I prove that if $\|S(x)\| = \|S^*(x)\|$ than $S$ is normal? ($SS^* = S^*S$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), show that if you have two linear maps $T,R \colon V \rightarrow V$ such that $\left< Tv, v \right> = \left< Rv, v \right>$ for  all $v \in V$ then $T = R$. Apply this to $T = SS^{*}$ and $R = S^{*}S$.

Comment: For more details, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587068/consequence-of-the-polarization-identity/1587131#1587131.

Comment: awesome it was that easy.. thanks!