# $0 ≤ A ≤ I. $ $\iff$ ⟨ψ|A|ψ⟩ ∈ [0, 1] for every unit vector $|ψ⟩ ∈ H$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, positive-definite, quantum-mechanics, self-adjoint-operators

Given two operators $A $and$ B$, where $A ≤ B$ means the operator
$B − A$ is positive semidefnite.

(i) $0 ≤ A ≤ I.$

(ii) ⟨ψ|A|ψ⟩ ∈ [0, 1] for every unit vector $|ψ⟩ ∈ H$
are equivalent

I am having trouble proving $(ii) \implies (i)$

If I take any non zero vector $|\phi⟩ $, then pluging in  $|\phi⟩|/\|\phi|\| $is  aunit vector which implies $0\le ⟨\phi|A|\phi⟩\le \|\phi|\| ^2$

Then I wanted to use $(d)\iff (a)$ in the proposition below  to conclude that A is positive semidefnite, but for that first I need to prove that A is hermitian and I can't figure out how to do that.
Any idea?

---

Proposition For a Hermitian operator A ∈ L(H),
the following fve conditions are equivalent:

(a) A is positive semidefnite.

(b) A = $B^†B$ for an operator B ∈ L(H).

(c) A = $B^†B$ for an operator B ∈ L(H, K) and some Hilbert space K.

(d) ⟨ψ|A|ψ⟩ ≥ 0 for every |ψ⟩ ∈ H.

(e) Tr[AC] ≥ 0 for every C ∈ PSD(H)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi | A |\psi\rangle&\leq 1\\
&= \langle \psi | \psi \rangle
\end{align*}
therefore $\langle \psi | A-I | \psi \rangle \leq 0$. You also have $0\leq \langle \psi|A|\psi\rangle$ and both for all $\psi$ unitary which you can now scale. Therefore $0\preccurlyeq A\preccurlyeq I$

Comment: I did manage to arrive to that expression as well, but I don't know how you can conclude that the matrix is hermitian from that. You need A and I-A to be hermitian before applying the proposition  $(d)\implies (a)$For that it sufficies to see that A is hermitian but I am stuck there

Comment: @darkside The proof that $A$ is Hermitian is well-known. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587131 for instance.